# Update Magento from 1.4.1.1 to 1.4.2 not completed, no mage directory

Tags: magento, ssh

To upgrade my Magento store from 1.4.1.1 to the latest version following this upgrade guide: http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/
I was getting a lot of error; deprecated messages. Probably because I'm am working on a PHP 5.3 server.

I did get through the first steps but then get this option:
`pear optional feature web installer available`

Decided to ignore that,
But when I get to the step where I have to

> chmod 550 ./mage
>
> ./mage mage-setup .

I get an `error saying, no such file or directory`.

It seems that the update tot 1.4.2 was not completed. Or at least the mage directory was not installed/downloaded.

Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deprecated messages are normal. Thats just pear in its way. just ignore them untill finished upgrading.
Also mage is a file, not a directory.

Where it goes wrong is: you execute 2 commands as one. Chmod doesn't like that.
Change it to:

```
chmod 550 ./mage 
./mage mage-setup
```

if you still get the file not found. This means the file mage is missing.
You can make sure that you are in the right magento root directory (e.g. /var/www/magento).
So make sure you cd to the right directory.

Or you come from an older version of magento and the mage file is really missing. This can be solved by using:

```
./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable
```

This will upgrade the magento to the most latest (beware that it can create problems, so try it on a development environment first).

Hope this helps you to get it working.

Comment: Thanks, but I never executed two files as one. But suddenly, the .mage file appeared on my server. Now I'm getting a "channel-add: Channel ‘community’ already exist" when I try to ./mage mage-setup .

Comment: Than its already initialized, you can continue with the rest of the upgrade. The mage-setup is used to initialize all the different repositories (and some more initial things). If its already setup. Its fine.